# firefox - how to adjust list of "start once" tabs from add-ons?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

When installing firefox add-ons, there are sometimes information tabs that are intended to be displayed only once.

My issue is that everytime i open a new window, that tab keeps comming up. Is there a file somewhere I can edit to stop this thing from popping up

win 7 x64
specific extension: Automatic Save Folder
the tab page it keeps opening up: chrome://asf/content/help/update.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [others](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/automatic-save-folder/) have complained about it as well.

Try this:

1. In Firefox press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, go to the **Help** menu and select **Troubleshooting Information**
2. Click the **Show Folder** button to open your **Profile Folder** in Windows Explorer
3. ***Close* Firefox**
4. Open **prefs.js** in Notepad
5. Search for `user_pref("extensions.asf.version", "");` and replace with

   `user_pref("extensions.asf.version", 18);`
6. Save and close the file
7. Restart Firefox and see if it helped (if not, you can try editing **18** to an even higher number)

<sub>[Source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/946971#answer-399176)</sub>

Comment: awesome. It is really wierd tho (as others have commented in the source link) I would have expected the version number to be the latest version of the extension, not the version of Firefox. In anycase, seems to have worked! thx! (+1 for source)